# "Open Classic Properties for More Color Options" options

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista

In Windows Vista, there used to be an option to "Open classic properties for more color options". I can't seem to find this in Windows 7. Is it no longer available? If it is still available, how does one get to it?  All I have in in Windows 7, under "Windows Color and Appearance" is "Advanced Appearance Settings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried actually clicking on that? It's exactly the same link, just with another caption ...